# DirectoryInfo[] SearchOption.AllDirectories doesn't include root directory?

Tags: c#, directoryinfo

Maybe this is by design, but I want to have C:\ in my root directory even if I already have that information.

```
DirectoryInfo Dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
DirectoryInfo[] directories = Dinfo .GetDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

So how do you get directories to include @"C:\?

Comment: @GrantWinney dumb design in my opinion

Comment: @Mike: Why should a method that recursively searches children include the parent? You already have the parent, hence it's no problem to include it yourself if you want, but it's more difficult and less efficient to remove something that you don't want to include.

Comment: For what it's worth, the [documentation for SearchOption.AllDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) itself is contradictory, and supports OP's assumption: "Includes the current directory and all its subdirectories in a search operation. This option includes reparse points such as mounted drives and symbolic links in the search."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add it with `Concat`:

```
DirectoryInfo[] directories = new[]{Dinfo}
    .Concat(Dinfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    .ToArray();
```